# sniff admin user name and password when remotely accessing

Tags: router, administrator, remote

so my ISP doesn't allow me to fully configure my router with the default access control, eg: if you want certain port open you need to call the ISP tell them which port and they open it by remotely accessing the router, so my question is can i sniff the admin username and password just when they remotely access my router? thx

Comment: You cannot.  They are accessing it from their network (which you have no access to) which means you cannot monitor the traffic on that network.  You also would be face with the fact the connection would be secure, which means its encrypted, and you have no way of performing a MiTM attack on the connection to your router.

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot do this. As Ramhound explains, they are accessing it from their own network.

I would recommend that you ask your ISP to put your router into Bridged mode. This will make the router act like a bridge instead of a router.

You can then go buy your own router and use that instead to apply all the port forwardings and other networking settings you might need.